# Access to AngularJS 1.6 component function from simple outside javascript code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

I need to call a function defined in a component of my AngularJS 1.6 app but i need to do this in simple javascript code outside the angular app. How can I do this?

Comment: I not gonna ask why would you wanna do this and the answer provided by @ArpadBajzath seems like it will work but is a really bad practice that eventually will bite you or the maintainers. Said that, but if you want to test something quick and dirty you could probably try that.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav, my main point to do this is beacuse i want to embed this component in a external bootstrap modal and I need to press a button on the component to close this modal and do other actions. If you can give me some tips on how to do it in a better way I would appreciate this.

Comment: So, why don't create a directive that wraps the bootstrap modal or even better use angular bootstrap. May be this will help https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#modal

Comment: Thanks,  I'll check it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using a standard event-broadcasting will help you.

Inside your component:

`document.addEventListener('trigger-my-method', () => myMethod());`

Somewhere else:

`let myEvt = new Event('trigger-my-method');
document.dispatchEvent(myEvt)`

Edit:
I'm not tested this solution, and i'm not deep into angular, but it should work

Comment: Thanks for answering, i not understand the way you tell me. Can you please give me an example with the following code? This is my component:

Comment: Thank you very much @ArpadBajzath, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test something quick and dirty, the function can be accessed from the Developer Console with:

```
scope = angular.element($0).isolateScope();
scope.$ctrl.myFunction();
```

Where `$0` is set by selecting the component by using `right click -> Inspect` or clicking the element in the element window of the Developer Console.

For more information, see [AngularJS angular.element API Reference - jQuery/jqLite Extras](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#jquery-jqlite-extras)